# How can I multiply the entrie in an array?

Tags: javascript

I wish to duplicate the data in an array to test performance. I tried

```
var users = data.data
console.log(users.length)
users.concat(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)))
console.log(users.length)
```

`Users` is an array.
It outputs 30 each time, even with the JSON-hack. How can I achive a duplication of the data?

Comment: You want the array to be twice as long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you're using JSON methods, but if you want to add the same content to the end, just grab the return value of `.concat()`.

```
users = users.concat(users);
```

If you needed to  make deep copies of the content, then you can use a simple loop with a deep copy function that I'm sure you'll find online. The JSON technique doesn't handle all data types, so be careful with that one.

If you needed to mutate the original, and if the Array isn't too long, then you can do this:

```
users.push.apply(users, users);
```

Very long arrays can fail. I think it's something like 150,000 items in the Array. So if that's the case, you'll need to break it up into batches, or just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `concat` does not alter the array, it returns a new one

So you could do

```
users = users.concat(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)));
```

for deep copy.

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method **returns a new array** comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.